After (apparent) 27/October/2024 update: Desktop Shuts-down by itself, now won't turn on
After assembling my own PC and struggling to install 24.04.1 LTS, I took my PC to a professional who corrected several mistakes I made during assembly and Installed Ubuntu PRO 24.04.1 LTS.
I have been using the PC for around a week, mostly Gaming with Steam, watching youtube videos and using Duolingo, when this morning I apparently received an update, allowed it to install, and then my PC started to shut down every 10-20 minutes, leading me to attempt to find a hardware fault, using some compressed air to dust the case interior, and when I finished and reconnected all external cables, my PC no-longer turns on.

Hardware fault, we cannot help you with that. You may want to take the PC to a professional again.

If you let fans spin with compressed air, you can burn out the fan controller and possibly more.   Or you could have dialoged something.   Possibly you had a software issue that compressed air can't fix.  Now you have damaged hardware.
